# Get nil value of unknown type from core function

Tags: go

I have a function that returns `interface`, sometimes my function should returns nil. but I want to return `nil` of the requested type.

I do handle this problem by creating another function to handle.

```
func GetNilOfType(needType string) interface{}{
    switch needType {
        case "string":
            return ""
        case "int":
        case "int32":
        case "int64":
            return 0
        case "float32":
        case "float64":
            return 0.0
        //... other types
    }
    return nil
}
```

My question: Is there a `core function` to handle it or should I create my own function?

ps. sorry for my complex expression. I hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: Not by the string type name, but a more elegant solution could use `reflect.Zero()`.

Comment: @icza I do upvote but this isn't my answer. I want to handle this response in another function. like ``` result.(string)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no standard library functions that work with types specified as a string name.  You can use a example value and [reflect.Zero](https://godoc.org/reflect#Zero) as suggested in a comment by icza:

```
func GetNilOfType(valueOfType interface{}) interface{}{
     return reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(valueOfType)).Interface()
}
```

Call it like this:

```
x := GetNilOfType(int32(123))
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6GFUVwwSFSt).

You will need to write your own function to specify the type by name.  Use a map in the implementation:

```
var zeros = map[string]interface{}{
    "string": "",
    "int16":  int16(0),
    "int8":   int8(0),
    "int":    int(0),
    "int32":  int32(0),
    "int64":  int64(0),
    // ... and so on
}

func GetNilOfType(name string) interface{} {
    x, ok := zeros[name]
    if !ok {
        panic("oops")
    }
    return x
}
```

None of the above is better than using a literal for the zero of the type:

```
x := int32(0)
y := (*MyType)(nil)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no core (builtin) function to return the zero value of a given type. However, you can write your own with reflect. Something like:

```golang
func zero(sample interface{}) interface{} {
    return reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(sample))
}
```

You can use it like:

```golang
zero("somestring").(string)
```

You do need to provide a value from which the type is extracted; you can't provide a type directly as you would with `make` or `new`.